# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method acceptadd(String) from the type teaminfo

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Currently, I am trying to make a couple of methods access each other. However, I am getting an error that I have not been able to figure out.

This is the error I get:

Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method acceptadd(String) from the type teaminfo

I looked to see if a method or a variable was static when it was not supposed to be, but neither the method acceptadd(String) or the method I am calling it from is static. I have no idea on how to fix it on this point, can someone help me?

Here's my code for GuiAddReject:

http://pastebin.com/Yj1Ny5Pz

The error Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method acceptadd(String) from the type teaminfo is at this line:

```
        teaminfo.acceptadd(playername);
```

Here is teaminfo.java:

http://pastebin.com/NxM8rwrE

Any help would be appreciated.

Also, sorry about the links, couldn't get the code brackets to work...

Comment: Please use pastebin or post your code here, no mediafire links thanks

Comment: I'm adding the pastebin now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that you are trying to access a non-static method (`acceptadd`) from a static context (i.e. not from an object). To solve this you need to make an object of the class to which the method you want to call belongs and call the method from its reference.

for example the correct way would be:

```
teaminfo tf = new teaminfo();
tf.acceptadd(playername);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're trying to call an *instance* method as if it were static.

On the line that you cited:

```
teaminfo.acceptadd(playername);
```

`teaminfo` is a *class* name, not a variable referring to an *instance* of that class. You want to create a teaminfo object somewhere in your project, e.g. in GuiAddReject, and call the methods on that object.

Comment: +1. @Rainfur: if you had respected Java naming conventions, and called your class TeamInfo instead of teaminfo, you would have noticed it immediately: `TeamInfo.foo()`: static method call. `teamInfo.foo()`: instance method call.